# Function for getting the winner at a given instant of time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dictionary, time-complexity, memoization

I want to discuss with smarter programmers this question which was asked in a recent interview, walk you through my approaches and ask how would you solve this problem efficiently. Will really appreciate your insights :)

Suppose you are given an array:

```
 arr = [[sam,123],[ram,124],[kris,125],[hen,127],[kris,135], [sam,140],...]
```

where each cell represents a candidate name and the timestamp (which is increasing and new records are being added continuously). This array can have millions of records.

*Write a function findWinner(arr, timestamp) which returns the name of the winner till that timestamp, given timestamp may or may not be in the given array. For tie print "tie"*

My approaches:

Approach 1:

```
a. Create a function voteCount(mydict, a) which takes an entry a and stores the count of each candidate in a dictionary and returns a dictionary say mydict
b. Create a function getMax(mydict) which takes the dictionary mydict created and sorts the dictionary with respect to values(count here), checks if there is a repeat (names) with respect to max as one edge case and print out "tie" or prints out the name of the max candidate
c. Create a function findWinner(arr, timestamp) which takes the input array arr, and a given timestamp and iterate through each entry in the array untill the given timestamp and take the name arr[i][0] and call voteCount(mydict, arr[i][0]) on it. 
d. After the loop finishes run getMax on mydict and print out the results
```

*`I was thinking of memoization in this scenario because there was no space constraints`*

Approach 2:

```
a. Create a datastructure Node with a name and count like the one below:

class Node
 attr_accessor :name, :count
 def initialize(name,count)
  @name = name
  @count = count
 end
end
b. In the getMax(mydict), take each key value pair as a node in a heap and run a max-heapify function with node.count and print out the root name(For edge case of tie, we can check with root's left child and right child)
```

Comment: Can you attach code to the process that adds new items to the array?

Comment: @hatchet: Hey! :) The interviewer didn't give that, he asked directly if this is how the data is given how would you approach the problem.

Comment: What is a winner? Does each element in the array represent a vote, and the time of the vote? What if there is a tie at the point in time being queried?

Comment: @hatchet Winner is the one with maximum vote count till a given input time from start, where each cells in the input array represents a vote(name, timestamp) and timestamp is continullay increasing. As I already specified in my appraoch, if its a tie we can print "tie" otherwise print name of the candidate

Comment: What does it mean to solve it efficiently? Efficient solution is different if the function will be called only once or if it will be called many times. Also, is number of candidates limited and known in advance? Also, what does it mean that records are being added simultaneously? Where are they being added to? How is the input actually organized? Is timestamp parameter the current timestamp so we are only interested in current result, or are we interested in previous results as well?

Comment: @Dialecticus For the solutions I thought, and discussed with the interviewer, I had to run these three functions(called by the main) each time a new query was made for any timestamp, the best I could think afterwards was using binary search algorithm to reduce linear search complexity. I am requesting if there are better solutions available in time and space complexity. Say this is the live feed and votes are being added, so names and timestamp(like 125) can change. But timestamp is increasing in each new input added to the input array arr. timestamp for querying can be anytime.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `SortedMap<Integer, Set<String>>` (e.g. a red-black tree), where the keys are timestamps and the values are the names of the winners at that timestamp.  Also create a `Map<String, Integer>` where the keys are names and the values are scores (initialized to zero).  Next, iterate through the array:

```
SortedMap<Integer, Set<String>> timestampMap = new RedBlackTree()
Map<String, Integer> scoreMap = new HashMap()
Set<String> currentWinners

foreach [name, timestamp] in array {
  int currentNameScore = scoreMap.get(name) + 1
  scoreMap.put(name, currentNameScore)
  int currentWinnerScore = scoreMap.get(currentWinners.first())
  if(currentWinners.contains(name) || currentNameScore > currentWinnerScore) {
    currentWinners = new Set(name)
  } else if(currentWinnerScore == currentNameScore) {
    currentWinners = currentWinners.copy().add(name)
  }
  timestampMap.put(timestamp, currentWinners)
}
```

You use the `Map` to keep track of each name's current score, then you determine if the name's score now equals or exceeds the current winner's score.  Querying the `SortedMap` for a given timestamp (or immediately preceding timestamp if the given key isn't present) is an O(log(n)) operation.  (See for example [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#tailMap(K)) as an example of typical operations on a `SortedMap`) Initializing the `SortedMap` is an O(n * log(n)) operation, so it only makes sense to use this approach if you're making several queries on the data (otherwise your linear search is faster).

Comment: I was writing an answer, but it's so similar to yours, it would be a duplicate now. The main difference is that the winner map only needs to record the winner at the points where the winner changes from its previous value. And in the case of tie, all that needs to be noted is "tie", not the list of winners (per the OP's clarification).

Comment: @hatchet I hadn't seen his clarification - in that case the `SortedMap<Integer, Set<String>>` is just a `SortedMap<Integer, String>`